# How to commit to main and not have it overridden when I merge dev to main afterwards?

Tags: git, git-merge

If I have a file A.

On the main branch I make changes to A, I then checkout a new branch dev and make other changes to A (working on a new feature f1).
I still didn't finish the feature f1 that I am working on in dev, but I want to add a different feature f2 that is not related to the feature f1 and therefore I want do it on main (or on a different branch, e.g. dev2) while I still haven't merged dev to main.

How can I do it?

My understating is that if I just checkout main (or dev2) and then add the feature f2, then later when I merge dev to main because dev didn't have the feature f2 it will override main and remove the feature.

Comment: Sounds like it should give you a merge-conflict if that were to happen. You can test it out locally, reset, and not push it to your origin.

Comment: It would not necessarily remove the minor change ... only if the changes in dev were to actually alter that part of the code. In general, you want to pull `main`, before you merge `dev` back in, and of course resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: Maybe you have a misunderstanding of how merge works? If you have "a minor change that is not related" on one branch, then when you "merge" it with a change on another branch, it won't "override it and remove the minor change". Instead, it will "merge" the two changes. More than 99% of the time, the automatic merge will do exactly what you want, but you should still consider looking at the result of the merge to be certain. If the automatic merge can't occur because the same lines are being modified, then you'll get a merge conflict. ("Unrelated" implies different lines so you should be fine.)

Answer (score 1):

> My understating is that if I just checkout main (or dev2) and then add the feature f2, then later when I merge dev to main because dev didn't have the feature f2 it will override main and remove the feature.

That's a wrong understanding. A merge, by its very nature, includes the contribution that happened in *both* wings of the merge. That's why it's called a merge!

If a feature is added in `main` since its divergence from `dev`, then when `dev` is merged into `main`, that feature will still be there, because it is a contribution that happened in `dev`. And whatever was done in `dev` will be there *too*.

Comment: It might help you to read my explanation of how merge works: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: Yeah, but when I merge I get a merge-conflict. Is there a way to work on different features in the same file from 2 different branches and then not get a merge-conflict?

Comment: Merge conflicts are not some bad thing. It just means it would be dangerous for Git to do this entirely automatically. It is asking for a little help. Help it and move on. No problem. — Please read the article I pointed you to.